# Debian Lenny Solr Jetty install + running

Tags: solr, debian, jetty, lenny

I want to setup search for my site. I couldn't find much information to install Jetty + Solr on my linode.

I could install solr-jetty on ubuntu simply using apt-get. any body has better experience with debian?

Comment: You can switch to Linode rival - Slicehost. They have Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: I get more memory in linode. atleast I can use that extra memory for search and memcached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to install it through the package manager. Jetty is deployed with Solr from the Solr homepage. So long as you have java installed on your server you can simply unpack the Solr distibution, read example/README.txt